# Not understandable content loadtxt csv from excel

Tags: arrays, regex, numpy

1) given below txt file:

[image]

2) import straight into array:

```
from numpy import loadtxt

def TestImport():
    HeadersPath = 'C:/mypath/Headers_20170602.txt'
    Header = loadtxt(HeadersPath,dtype=str,delimiter="/t" )

    print Header

TestImport()
```

3) gives me the following output:

```
%run "C:/mypath/TestCSVImport.py"
['\xff\xfe1\x00\t\x002\x00\t\x003\x00\t\x004' '' '']
```

Why don't I see 1,2,3,4?

Comment: Just tried locally: I get the line as is. If I change `/t` to `\t`, I get `['1' '2' '3' '4']`. Your file is in UTF16. Save in UTF8 without BOM, or use ANSI encoding.

Comment: '\t' gives me a 'ValueError: cannot set an array element with a sequence' 
So loadtxt does not support UTF16?

Comment: `np.loadtxt(filename,delimiter='\t',dtype=int)` attempts to open the file in 'rb' mode (for Python3), split on tabs, and return values as integers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Pandas module:

```
import pandas as pd

arr = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/file.csv', sep='\t', header=None).values
```

or:

```
arr = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/file.csv', sep='\t', header=None, encoding='utf-16').values
```